# Css menu item with corners rounded to outside

Tags: css, menuitem, bootstrap-5, rounded-corners

I working on a web app that has a vertical side menu. I want the active menu item link to have corners that are rounded to outside as in the picture.
I saw the question in [CSS MENU with rounded corners and inner corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30502269/css-menu-with-rounded-corners-and-inner-corners), but didnt work for me. I tried border radius with negative values but  also didnt work. Any ideas?

I'm using bootstrap 5

[image: menu item]

Comment: This is not a "Code it for you " Service. What did you try? What worked? What didn't work?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and tell us what you have researched.

Comment: A complicated solution is [here](https://css-tricks.com/tabs-with-round-out-borders/). Clicking on some areas doesn't work, it's discussed there in the comments.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601317/css-to-create-curved-corner-between-two-elements https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58335709/css-trick-to-make-border-radius-from-outside-div

Comment: Slightly related: https://css-tricks.com/gooey-effect/